# AngularJS local include error

Tags: angularjs

i have a problem with the angularjs includes.
When i include the angular scrips direct from the website

everything works fine.

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

When i set the link local :

```
<script src="../scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I go some errors:

```
ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
    at angular-route.min.js:8
    at angular-route.min.js:16
```

I thing the sources are the same???

I user Win 8 und Visual Studio 2015 and AngularJs 1.6.0.

THX

Comment: include `angular.min.js` first.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the local scripts are located in the path you are using. 
In accordance to your question, they should be in the scripts directory that is located in the parent directory of the file where you are including the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You should include `angular.min.js` first. And be sure that your path is correct.

Comment: OK, i copy all files in the same folder, so i should have not any path problems. 
But the angulasjs don't work without any errors.